# Why String variables are needed to be initialized and sometimes it doesn't required initialization while declaring them in java?

Tags: java, string, initialization, applet, paint

I was writing an simple applet program that takes an input from the user and displays them. `

```
public void init(){
    text1=new TextField(8);

    add(text1);

    text1.setText("0");

}
public void paint(Graphics g){
    int x=0;
    String s1,str = null;
    g.drawString("input in the  box",10,50);
    try{
        s1=text1.getText();
        str=String.valueOf(s1);


    }
    catch(Exception e){}
    g.drawString(str,75,75);
}
public boolean action (Event event,Object object){
    repaint();
    return true;
}
```

`
in the paint() method why is that str variable must be declared to null while declaring the other string variable s1 without initialization is okay?
IT doesn't compile without initialization the str variable.

Comment: *"why is that str variable must be declared to null"* FWIW, the `= null` bit isn't a *declaration*, it's an *initialization*.

Comment: that's initializing both variables to be null, not just str. You can declare a variable in different ways. See this: http://www.learnjavaonline.org/en/Variables_and_Types

Comment: @Phobos That only applies to the last variable. To initialize both you would need `String s1 = null, str = null;`.

Comment: Don't catch just `Exception` (if you can help it), and don't ignore exceptions like you do here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you only use the value of `s1` in a place where it's guaranteed to have a value, but you use `str` in a place (the `catch` handler) where it *isn't* guaranteed to have a value if you don't initialize it to something up front, since after all, an exception could be thrown in the `try` prior to assigning to `str`.

If you moved the call to `g.drawString(str,75,75);` *into* the `try`, you wouldn't need the `= null` initializer.

---

Side note: `s1` is already a string, so there's no need to do `str = String.valueOf(s1)`. Just use `s1` in the `g.drawString(str,75,75);` line.

Answer (score 0):

The Java compiler allows uninitialized variables as long as they're guaranteed to have a value by the time they're used for something.

```
String s1,str = null; // s1 is not set
g.drawString("input in the  box",10,50);
try{
    s1=text1.getText(); // s1 is set
    str=String.valueOf(s1); // s1 is used
}
catch(Exception e){}
g.drawString(str,75,75);
```

Since the previous line initialized `s1`, it can safely be passed to `String.valueOf`.

The problem with `str` is that it's used after the try-catch block, which might skip the line where it's set.

```
String s1,str; // str is not set
g.drawString("input in the  box",10,50);
try{
    s1=text1.getText(); // if this throws an exception...
    str=String.valueOf(s1); // ...this is never reached
}
catch(Exception e){} // the exception is caught and ignored, so we continue
g.drawString(str,75,75); // str is still not set - error!
```

As long as there's the possibility that a variable is used before initialization, the compiler will reject it. In this case, you could set `str` to a default value in the catch block, or `return` or `throw` from the catch block so that the `g.drawString` line is only reached if the try block completes without exception.

Answer (score 0):

instance variable don't require initialization and only local variables (which are inside of function or a constructor) are required to be initialized)